# Select item numbers ordered twice within a date range, sql

Tags: sql, select, date-range

I am currently working in sql studio 2012. I have a table with columns DateOrdered, ItemNumeber, and requestor. I am trying to write a select statement that will pull a list of item numbers that have been ordered twice within a period of 7 days. The item number could be a different person or the same person.

Comment: Do you mean within *any* 7-day period ? or just within a specific 7-day period ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana any 7 day period

Answer (score 1):

If you mean within any 7-day period then that is equivalent to "list of item numbers that have been ordered within 7 days of another order",  right ?

If so, then

```
     Select distinct ItemNumber
     From table t
     Where exists 
          (Select * From table 
           where itemNumber = t.ItemNumber
             and DateOrdered > t.DateOrdered  
             and DateOrdered < t.DateOrdered + 7)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the part about being ordered twice.

Comment: Yes, it does.  If another record exists for the same item within the 7 day period, that other record represents a second order,

Comment: This almost works but it is not capturing duplicate part numbers. Can you help with this Dan?

Comment: What do you mean "duplicate part numbers" ? are you talking about *Item* Numbers  ?  If you are, what do you mean "capturing"?  Do you want to see the same itemNumber output twice ?

Answer (score 1):

The having clause is your freind.

```
select someFields, count(*) records
from someTables
where some conditions are met
group by someFields
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This brings back my item numbers but is there a way I can see the date they were ordered as well. Instead of having a count, just make a list with the item numbers duplicated down the list with the order date beside them.

Comment: I got it figured out, this solution best fit my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: modified after comments.

```
select * from table a
inner join table b
  on a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber
  and Abs(datediff(DD, a.dateordered, b.dateordered)) <= 7
  and a.ID < b.ID --or something like this to ensure you don't return matches that are actually the same row.  If you don't have an ID and the date ordered is unique for each order, replace ID with that
```

This will return the orders in pairs, if you need the two orders/dates together.  If you just want a list, use:

```
select distinct a.itemnumber from table a
inner join table b
  on a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber
  and Abs(datediff(DD, a.dateordered, b.dateordered)) <= 7
  and a.ID <> b.ID --or something like this to ensure you don't return matches that are actually the same row.  If you don't have an ID and the date ordered is unique for each order, replace ID with that
```

Note, this will return anything ordered at least twice - if you need only things ordered exactly twice, you will need a different query.

Comment: I also have a quantity column that I did not mention. It seems like your bottom query is duplicating that quantity. The quantity column is an int.

Comment: @Cheddar what do you mean by duplicating?  The `select distinct` should eliminate any duplicates.  How did you modify the query to incorporate your quantity column?